# IIS manager does not show machine.config changes

Tags: frameworks, iis-7.5, iis-manager, machine.config

I'm trying to add these lined to machine.config file:

```
 <processModel autoConfig="true" maxWorkerThreads = "100" maxIoThreads = "100" />
<system.net>
  <connectionManagement>
      <add address="*" maxconnection="100" />
  </connectionManagement>
</system.net>
```

machine.config file is in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config

I change it, save it, even restart the computer. but when I open IIS manager, click on computer name on left tree (top item) and click  "configuration editor" maxWorkerThreads =20 and maxIoThreads =20 and system.net maxconnection item does not exists.

I cannot change values from IIS manager because they are locked. I tried to unlock them but nothing enabled them.

I alsto tried to change 32bit version of framework config:
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config

even I mess tieh machine.config and put a syntax error in it, IIS manager shows same default values.
though I googled for hours I could find any solution.

how can I check if machine.config changes are effective ? Why I cannot see them on IIS manager.

I tried same operation won windows8.1 and as soon as I change machine.config IIS manager shows them.

help please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems windows 8.1 does it immediately.

I started to change all machine.config files one by one. When I chaged framework 2.0 machine.config file I saw them in IIS manager.

It seems windows8.1 IIS manager reads ans uses framework4 values for its default (or top level on the left) machine config. but windows7 IIS manager uses framework2.0 as default.

looked weird to me. anyway result is yau need to change all machine.config files.

you cannot see "running values" of any application pool one by one.

Answer (score 0):

IIS Manager displays the latest .NET framework version, but you can change that in the "Change .NET Framework Version" task that is shown in the right when you are at the "Server level". Note that this task only changes the "management experience" and has no side effect.

When you are at a site level or below (like an App or a folder), IIS Manager will figure out the right .NET version from the configuration of the site/app and use that one, including the decision of which .NET version (like 2.0, 4.0, etc) but also the "bitness" (like 32-bit or 64-bit) which would map to the right folder.